# Graphene AssertionError: Can't find type in schema

Tags: python, types, interface, graphql, graphene-python

I create such schema using [graphene v2.1.8](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/tree/v2.1.8) and looking into [this example](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/blob/v2.1.8/examples/starwars/schema.py):

```
class Employee(graphene.Interface):
    employee_id = graphene.ID()
    employee_type = graphene.Field(lambda: EmployeeType)

    @classmethod
    def resolve_type(cls, instance, info):
        if instance.get("employee_type") == EmployeeType.PART_TIME.name:
            return PartTimeEmployee
        return FullTimeEmployee


class PartTimeEmployee(graphene.ObjectType):
    class Meta:
        interfaces = (Employee, )


class FullTimeEmployee(graphene.ObjectType):
    class Meta:
        interfaces = (Employee, )
```

When I run query against it I got following error:

> AssertionError: Can't find type PartTimeEmployee in schema

What do I do wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If types `PartTimeEmployee`, `FullTimeEmployee` do not mentioned explicitly 
 in Query classes - you have to register types in `Schema` manually.

```
schema = Schema(query=Query, types=[PartTimeEmployee, FullTimeEmployee])
```